# Add tracking code to success.phtml

Tags: confirmation

I am looking to add the following tracking code to the checkout confirmation page on our magento site but am unsure on what to add/change so that it reflects the order details. Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var _caq = _caq || [];
            var products = [];
            products.push({Sku: 'ProductID', UnitPrice: 'item price here', Quantity: 'quantity here'});
            products.push({Sku: 'ProductID', UnitPrice: 'item price here', Quantity: 'quantity here'});
            _caq.push(["Order", {OrderId: 'OrderID', Revenue: 'oVal', CurrencyCode: '3 letter currency code here', Products: products}]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would go in your success page template, of course.  The default one is located at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml`:

```
<?php
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $currency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
            var _caq = _caq || [];
            var products = [];
            <?php foreach ($items as $item){
                    echo "products.push({Sku: '{$item->getSku()}', UnitPrice: '{$item->getPrice()}', Quantity: '{$item->getQtyOrdered()}'});\n";
                }
             echo "_caq.push(['Order', {OrderId: '{$order->getId()}', Revenue: '{$order->getGrandTotal()}', CurrencyCode: '{$currency}', Products: products}]);"; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: That's great thanks Don. Is there a subtotal alternative for getGrandTotal()?

Comment: Several, actually!  `getSubtotal()` will work, also `getSubtotalInclTax()` if you want tax added.  Here's a good reference: http://freegento.com/doc/functions_0x67.html#index_g

Comment: Exactly what I needed! :D Thanks for this answer!