# Avantlink Order Tracking on Confirmation Page

Tags: affiliate

I'm trying to get Avantlink's code into my order confirmation page.  The code *should* look like this when it's done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _AvantMetrics = _AvantMetrics || [];
_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:'[ORDER_ID]', amount:'[ORDER_AMOUNT]', state:'[BILLING_STATE]', country:'[BILLING_COUNTRY]' }]);
_AvantMetrics.push(['item',{ order_id:'[ORDER_ID]', parent_sku:'[ITEM_PARENT_SKU]', variant_sku:'[ITEM_VARIANT_SKU]', price:'[ITEM_PRICE]', qty:'[ITEM_QUANTITY]' }]);
</script>
```

Using this stack exchange article as a reference for adding success page confirmation: [Add tracking code to success.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25003/add-tracking-code-to-success-phtml)

Trying to put this into the bottom of success.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _AvantMetrics = _AvantMetrics || [];
<?php
$newOrderId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()); 
$newOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($newOrderId);
$items = $newOrder->getAllItems();
$currency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$billingAddress = $newOrder->getBillingAddress();

echo "_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:'{$newOrder->getId()}', amount:'{$newOrder->getGrandTotal()}', state:'{$billingAddress->getRegionId();}', country:'{$billingAddress->getCountry();}' }]);";

foreach ($items as $item){
    echo "_AvantMetrics.push(['item',{ order_id:'{$newOrder->getId()}', parent_sku:'{$item->getSku()}', variant_sku:'{$item->getSku()}', price:'{$item->getPrice()}', qty:'{$item->getQtyOrdered()}' }]);";
} ?>
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. When I do this, the success page breaks. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Here's my latest version of the code.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$amount = $order->getSubtotal();
$orderid = $order->getIncrementId();
$items = $order->getAllItems();

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "var _AvantMetrics = _AvantMetrics || [];
_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:'{$orderid}', amount:'{$amount}', state:'', country:'' }]);";

foreach($items as $item) {
  $_sku = $item->getSku();
  $_itemprice = $item->getPrice();
  $_itemqty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
  echo "_AvantMetrics.push(['item',{ order_id:'{$orderid}', parent_sku:'{$_sku}', variant_sku:'{$_sku}', price:'{$_itemprice}', qty:'{$_itemqty}' }]); ";
}
echo "</script>"
```

Echoed the entire javascript. And moved the magento calls to variables. Magento calls define variables in the foreach loop. And then the variables called in the echo.

The only issue with this code is that I don't differentiate between the parent & variant skus. This is fine for my purposes, but if you've got a complex site with lots of configurable products or custom options, you're going to want to figure that bit of code out.

Edit: I created a gist for this too: https://gist.github.com/sam327/d519b0ad78500dfc8ec1